# using "at" argument of margins function in R for logit model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, effect, margins

I want to be able to analyze the marginal effect of continuous and binary variables in a logit model. I am hoping for R to provide what the independent marginal effect of hp is at its mean (in this example that is at 200), while also finding the marginal effect of the vs variable equaling 1. I am hoping the output table also includes the SE, p value, and z score. I am having trouble with the table and when I have gotten it to run it doesn't evaluate the two variables independently. Here is an MRE below. Thank you!

```
mod2 <- glm(am ~ hp + factor(vs), data=mtcars, family=binomial)

margins(mod2)
#> Average marginal effects
#> glm(formula = am ~ hp + factor(vs), family = binomial, data = mtcars)
#>        hp      vs1
#>  -0.00203 -0.03154

#code where I am trying to evaluate at the desired values. 
margins(mod2, at=list(hp=200, vs=1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you've changed `vs` to a factor.
Consider the following

```r
library(margins)
mod3 <- glm(am ~ hp + vs, data=mtcars, family=binomial)
margins(mod3, at=list(hp=200, vs=1))

# Average marginal effects at specified values
# glm(formula = am ~ hp + vs, family = binomial, data = mtcars)
# 
#  at(hp) at(vs)        hp       vs
#     200      1 -0.001783 -0.02803
```

There is no real reason to turn `vs` into a factor here; it's dichotomous.

Comment: Ok thank you. Though with the output table, there is a column for the hp and vs variables such that they both equal the values specified in the code above. But with a regression isn't the purpose to isolate the marginal effect of those two variables? So shouldn't vs=0 when we are trying to look at the marginal effect at hp=200? Is there a way to do that, but also find the marginal effect of vs when it =1 and hp=0?

Comment: Ah, good point @juliah0494 will take a look at this in a few minutes

Comment: @juliah0494 Thinking about this, this is actually also why you probably made `vs` a factor, right? To ensure `margins()` does first differences rather than instantaneous change?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. That is the advice I'd received previously. However, when I do apply factor() to vs, I receive this error: "Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]"

Comment: Try to convert your binary to a factor before estimate, and to supply a factor with the same levels as the original variable to `at`. For instance, `at=list(vs=factor(1, levels=levels(dat$vs)))`

Comment: @Vincent, ok that did resolve the error message. However when I ran the code now there is a column displaying that vs=2 now. and it seems hp=200 still when  evaluate the marginal effect of vs=1. To isolate the marginal effect of a variable, I need all other variables to be at 0 correct?

Comment: The other variables can be whatever you want them to be. There is one marginal effect per combination of values of the regressors. My suspicion is that vs=2 might refer to the *factor level*, which is indexed starting at 1, so 0=1, and 1=2. But I'm not 100% sure how `margins` handles this internally.

Comment: @Vincent, ok interesting. Thank you for the insight. Do you know of other functions/packages in R that might be helpful for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Actually, I did a bit more research and it seems like the logitmfx function might be the solution? If I set the `atmean` argument to true, I think that will solve for the marginal effect at the mean.